# How to insert average for each column in SQL Server table with a condition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created a temporary table with dynamic columns. These columns are the values in a master table.

Say,

```
Id |Name
1  |Prepaid
2  |Postpaid
```

so the temporary table columns will be

```
Id Prepaid Postpaid
```

In this case the columns are dynamic.

consider the below code for temp table:

```
declare @temp as table (Id int, Prepaid float, postpaid float)

insert into @temp values(1,100,200)
insert into @temp values(1,10,500)
insert into @temp values(1,-100,-100)
insert into @temp values(1,10,200)
insert into @temp values(1,100,-100)
insert into @temp values(1,150,560)
insert into @temp values(1,90,200)
```

I need to insert a row with average of each column.

Average should be calculated taking the rows which meet the condition, i.e, the column should not contain a value `-100`.

I need to insert a row with average values like for the above values.

```
Id       PrepaidAvg      PostPaidAvg  
1     76.6666666666667  320
```

Comment: can you explain the conditions more fully please?  What does `-100, -100` mean?

Comment: Anand can you please refine your requirements? People are spending a lot of energy trying to figure out what you mean. It would be much easier if you just tell us what you mean. A simple start would be to show us what results you want instead of trying to describe them in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to determine exactly what result you expect, but here is one try:

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  PrepaidAvg = AVG(CASE WHEN Prepaid > 0 THEN Prepaid ELSE NULL END),
  PostpaidAvg = AVG(CASE WHEN postpaid > 0 THEN postpaid ELSE NULL END)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY Id;
```

If this is off you can get more elaborate:

```
;WITH prepaid AS
(
  SELECT Id, PrepaidAvg = AVG(Prepaid)
    FROM @temp WHERE Prepaid > 0
), postpaid AS
(
  SELECT Id, PostpaidAvg = AVG(postpaid)
    FROM @temp WHERE postpaid > 0
)
SELECT Id = COALESCE(prep.Id, postp.Id),
  prep.PrepaidAvg,
  postp.PostpaidAvg
FROM prepaid AS prep
FULL OUTER JOIN postpaid AS postp
ON prep.Id = postp.Id;
```

Comment: Do you think it should be `>= 0` instead?

Comment: @Raj maybe, it's hard to tell. He just said "-100" was no good. This could mean all negative numbers or all non-positive numbers. Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @JNK what do you mean? Sounded like he wanted the average of the two columns. Where would the other 8 columns come from?

Comment: @Aaron - sorry I misread.  He wants 10 rows, not columns.  Deleted the comment.

Comment: @JNK I'm still not sure exactly what is required. Don't know where you get 10 rows either, but I have absolutely no idea if my approach comes even close to getting the desired results. I like tabular desired results, not word problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
insert into @temp 
select avg(Id), avg(Prepaid), avg(postpaid)
from @temp 
where Prepaid <> -100 and postpaid <> -100
```